# Cleaning email for text analysis python

Tags: python, email

I've got some text:

```
text = From: Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Sent: Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM
To: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Cc: Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>
Subject: Request

 

This is the body of the first mail. That is
some further text.


Od: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Wysłano: środa, 2 lutego 2022 17:49
Do: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
DW: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Temat: RE: issue 43165

Here is the second email.

Signature. Yours sincerly. 
Best Regards



From: Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Sent: Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM
To: Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>
Subject: Without carbon copy
 

This is the last mail without Cc.
Kind regards

Mark
```

I'm trying to parse out the messages within them. Ultimately I'd like to have a list or dictionary where I have the From and To, and then the message body with which to do some analysis on.

The problem: There are two languages in it (english and polish -> From/Od). How do I have to change the regex in order to recognize both langues?

Code below is from [Cleaning email chain for text analysis python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676027/cleaning-email-chain-for-text-analysis-python):

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

groups = re.findall(r'^From:(.*?)To:(.*?)Subject:(.*?)$(.*?)(?=^From:|\Z)', text, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)
emails = []
for g in groups:
    d = {}
    d['from'] = g[0].strip()
    d['to'] = g[1].strip()
    d['subject'] = g[2].strip()
    d['message'] = g[3].strip()
    emails.append(d)

pprint(emails)
```

How do I have to change the following part?

```
groups = re.findall(r'^From:(.*?)To:(.*?)Subject:(.*?)$(.*?)(?=^From:|\Z)', text,
```

I thouth something like the following should work but only two entries are created:

```
groups = re.findall(r'^(From:(.*?)|Od:(.*?))(Sent:(.*?)|Wysłano:(.*?))(To:(.*?)|Do:(.*?))(Subject:(.*?)$(.*?)(?=^From:|\Z)|Temat:(.*?)$(.*?)(?=^Od|\Z))', text, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)

emails = []

for g in groups:
    d = {}
    d['From'] = g[0].strip()
    d['Sent'] = g[1].strip()
    d['To'] = g[2].strip()   
    d['Subject'] = g[3].strip()
    d['Body'] = g[4].strip()
    emails.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(emails)
df
```

Comment: There is really no good way to do this; cursed be Microsoft. The strings differ between versions of Outlook and there are hundreds of languages you need to collect samples of.

Comment: (Also, Edgar Allan Poe probably curses all the Americans who misspell his name.)

Answer (score 1):

Since all the parts have different versions (language, casing, like `Dw`and `DW`), I'd suggest to create a list for each and connecting them with `|` in non-capturing gorups (e.g. `(?:PATTERN)`).
You also need to add a part for `Sent` which is not included in the example liked. Since in the last mail the Cc is absent, I made that a optional group. The referecing is done by named groups (e.g. `(?P<some_name>PATTERN)`).
For compactness I omitted some part of the mails in the code.

```py
import re


pattern = r'^(?:From|Od):(?P<from>.*?)\n(?:Sent|Wysłano):(?P<sent>.*?)\n(?:To|Do):(?P<to>.*?)\n(?:(?:Cc|Dw|DW):(?P<cc>.*?)\n)?(?:Subject|Temat):(?P<subject>.*?)\n(?P<message>.*)$'

mails = ['''
From: Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Sent: Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM
To: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Cc: Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>
Subject: Request

This is the body of the first mail. That is
some further text.
''',
'''
Od: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Wysłano: środa, 2 lutego 2022 17:49
...
Best Regards
''',
'''
From: Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
...
This is the last mail without Cc.
Kind regards

Mark
''']

for mail in mails:
    matches = re.search(pattern, mail, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)
    print('To:', matches.group('to'))
    print('From:', matches.group('from'))
    print('Subject:', matches.group('subject'))
    print('Msg:', matches.group('message')[:50])  # cutoff for demonstration
    print('***')
```

Output:

```
To:  Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
From:  Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Subject:  Request
Msg:


This is the body of the first mail. That is
so
***
To:  Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
From:  Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Subject:  RE: issue 43165
Msg:
Here is the second email.

Signature. Yours since
***
To:  Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>
From:  Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Subject:  Without carbon copy
Msg:

This is the last mail without Cc.
Kind regards

***
```

Comment: ---> 33     print('To:', matches.group('to'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Yes, because the mail body is truncated in the example code. You need to a whole/valid mail body. I didn't want to paste 40 lines of strings above the actualy code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given you a regex answer, but I find that maintaining a single large regex becomes harder over time, especially if you want to add more fields to it.
Instead of using a regex to match everything in one go, you could parse the text line-by-line. Here, I use `io.StringIO` to iterate over the lines of `text`

This approach also has the advantage of not requiring all your fields to be in the same order, which is necessary for the regex approach shown in the other answer.

```
import io

def parse_emails(text):
    all_emails = []
    current_email = {}
    for line in io.StringIO(text):
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("From: ") or line.startswith("Od: "):
            # From indicates the start of a new message
            # If the current email is not an empty dict, append it to our list
            if current_email: 
                # Before appending, join the lines of the body into a single string
                current_email["body"] = "\n".join(current_email["body"]).strip()
                all_emails.append(current_email)
                current_email = {}
            current_email["from"] = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
        elif line.startswith("To: ") or line.startswith("Do: "):
            current_email["to"] = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
        elif line.startswith("Sent: ") or line.startswith("Wysłano: "):
            current_email["sent"] = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
        elif line.startswith("Cc: ") or line.startswith("DW: "):
            current_email["cc"] = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
        elif line.startswith("Subject: ") or line.startswith("Temat: "):
            current_email["subject"] = line.split(": ", 1)[1]
        # You can add more fields if you need to
        else:
            # Append each line of the body to a list, because a list is cheaper to append 
            # to than creating a whole new string. As seen above, we join
            # the elements of the list into a single string before finalizing this email
            current_email.setdefault("body", []).append(line)


    # After the text has ended, append the last email to the list
    if current_email:
        current_email["body"] = "\n".join(current_email["body"]).strip()
        all_emails.append(current_email)

    return all_emails
```

To test this, let's use your `text`:

```
text = """From: Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Sent: Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM
To: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Cc: Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>
Subject: Request

 

This is the body of the first mail. That is
some further text.


Od: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Wysłano: środa, 2 lutego 2022 17:49
Do: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
DW: Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>
Temat: RE: issue 43165

Here is the second email.

Signature. Yours sincerly. 
Best Regards



From: Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>
Sent: Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM
To: Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>
Subject: Without carbon copy
 

This is the last mail without Cc.
Kind regards

Mark"""

d = parse_emails(text)

print(d)
```

Which gives us our three emails, parsed into dictionaries with the correct keys:

```
[{'from': 'Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>',
  'sent': 'Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM',
  'to': 'Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>',
  'cc': 'Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>',
  'subject': 'Request',
  'body': 'This is the body of the first mail. That is\nsome further text.'},
 {'from': 'Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>',
  'sent': 'środa, 2 lutego 2022 17:49',
  'to': 'Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>',
  'cc': 'Edgar Allen Poe <eap@gmail.com>',
  'subject': 'RE: issue 43165',
  'body': 'Here is the second email.\n\nSignature. Yours sincerly.\nBest Regards'},
 {'from': 'Mark Twain <mark.twain@gmail.com>',
  'sent': 'Wednesday, February 2, 2022 1:33 PM',
  'to': 'Edgar Allen Poe1 <eap1@gmail.com>',
  'subject': 'Without carbon copy',
  'body': 'This is the last mail without Cc.\nKind regards\n\nMark'}]
```